# html.erb (how to specify both id and class) and combining haml code

Tags: jquery, html, ruby-on-rails, haml, erb

I have a line of code

```
<li class="m-bottom-20">
```

and

```
<li id="faq_<%= faq.id %>">
```

How do I combine these 2 lines to specify both class and id?
Also, I have another question concerning combining haml code. I have this line of haml code already

```
%li.m-bottom-20
```

but I need to replace it with this line

```
= content_tag_for :li, faq do
```

But still keep the formatting for li.

These 2 questions are actually referring to the same 2 lines of code, one in html.erb and one in haml.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify class and ids to li like this:

```
%li.m-bottom-20{id: "faq_#{faq.id}"}
```

or

```
= content_tag :li, class: "m-bottom-20", id: "faq_#{faq.id}" do
  "Some content"
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work:

```
%li.m-bottom-20{id: "faq_#{faq.id}"}
  = content_tag_for :li, faq do
```